# How can i print both key and values using minijson in unity3d

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine, monodevelop

I am using  minijson to get values from json in unity3d

Response is

```
{"existing":[{"LastUpdated":"7\/9\/2013 4:03:57 AM","LetterSpeed":100,"Letters":"SP","NumRandom":5,"Reward":10,"ShowWordDesc":false,"ShowWordHint":false,"Sort_ID":5,"WN_Level_ID":34,"WN_Word_ID":95,"WordDesc":"","WordHint":"","zError":null},{"LastUpdated":"7\/9\/2013 4:03:57 AM","LetterSpeed":100,"Letters":"aún","NumRandom":2,"Reward":10,"ShowWordDesc":true,"ShowWordHint":false,"Sort_ID":10,"WN_Level_ID":34,"WN_Word_ID":83,"WordDesc":"still","WordHint":"","zError":null},{"LastUpdated":"7\/9\/2013 4:03:58 AM","LetterSpeed":200,"Letters":"tanto","NumRandom":3,"Reward":10,"ShowWordDesc":true,"ShowWordHint":false,"Sort_ID":20,"WN_Level_ID":34,"WN_Word_ID":84,"WordDesc":"so","WordHint":"","zError":null}]}
```

Code i used is

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using MiniJSON;
```

In function

```
string response = www.text; 
Debug.Log(response);            
IDictionary search = (IDictionary) Json.Deserialize(response);
IList tweets = (IList) search["existing"];      
foreach (IDictionary tweet in tweets) {
    Debug.Log(tweet["LastUpdated"]);                
}
```

If i am unaware of key name, how can i save both keys and value?

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure what you're trying to get as output here but if I were to take a guess you want to do the following:

```
string response = www.text; 

Debug.Log(response); 

IDictionary search = (IDictionary) Json.Deserialize(response);

IList tweets = (IList) search["existing"];  

foreach (IDictionary tweet in tweets) {
    Debug.Log("Tweet details:");
    foreach( KeyValuePair<string, string> tweetData in tweet )  {
        Debug.Log("Key = " + tweetData.Key.ToString() +
                  " Value = " + tweetData.Value.ToString());
    }            
}
```

Comment: Fixed it up for the Unity Debug logger.

Comment: I don't believe that has anything to do with my code? Did you even check what line 42 is?

Comment: foreach( KeyValuePair<string, string> tweetData in tweet )  { this lines makes error: InvalidCastException: Cannot cast from source type to destination type.

Comment: I'm working blind here. You need to make sure that the string, string portion of the KeyValuePair match that of the Dictionary type of tweetData. It could be: KeyValuePair<string, object>

Comment: tried, but have same error. i given response in question. which helps you to find my error

Comment: i given print(tweet); so gets System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Object]